# How to write Redirect in asp website

Tags: asp-classic

Can any one help me, how to redirect http://www.xxxx.com/default.asp To http://www.xxxx.com in ASP

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your question is not clear . PLease see this faq : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you trying to remove the default.asp from the url and keep it just xxxx.com?

Comment: yes i am trying to remove the default.asp from the url using web.config file

Comment: easy using using HTML Redirect just add in head tag, <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.xxxx.com"> where 0 is seconds that you can change if required

Comment: @MarmiK: your suggestion will lead to a continuous loop because xxxx.com/default.asp is the same as xxxx.com

Comment: @smirnov : User can change the link, answer is in context to the question. We don't know if default page is index.asp in global settings.

Answer (score 1):

There are following options for classic ASP (.asp extensions)

- For IIS7 use built-in URL Rewrite module. Either create a new rule through IIS or locate following web.config file in the root folder of your web site

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="^default.asp$" />
                  <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
  ```
- For old IIS versions use third party ISAPI modules like [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/).

Answer (score -2):

If you use ASP .NET MVC you should add something like this in your **RouteConfig.cs** in the **RegisterRoutes** method:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "anyName", url: "/default", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

If you are using ASP. NET WebForms, you should try installing something like Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter : http://iirf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Redirection.

If you use IIS 7 or higher you could also try this : http://blog.pluralsight.com//iis7-redirect-windows-server-2008

Comment: How has this got two upvotes when the question is Classic ASP not ASP.Net?